# Sets and first order logic question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

this question has me stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

It goes like this:

> For the domain of all sets, give a first-order logic formula saying -
>   There exists no set such that all other sets are its element.

So far I have this:

Let $x$ and $y$ be all sets. $\lnot\exists x\,\forall\,y\,(y\in x \impliedby x\ne y)$

Note, the reason I've put $x$ does not equal $y$ is because the question says "all OTHER" sets, so I interpreted that as, it does not include itself, so it's not a member of itself but again I'm not sure.

Comment: $\neg (\exists x)(\forall y)(y \neq x \Rightarrow y \in x)$

Comment: @Clay I was wrong, William is correct, except for he should be using $\to$ instead of $\implies$, ^_^.

Comment: @William why not post it as an answer?

Comment: I couldn't read all the funky characters to format them properly, so I had to guess.

Comment: @GitGud Actually I think my formula is incorrect. The whole universe could be such an $x$. I should add $\wedge x \notin x$.

Comment: @William What's the problem with $x\in x$? We're not interested in the logical value of the statement, we're only interested in writing the statement in FOL. What's wrong with your suggestion?

Comment: @GitGud As I understood the statement, the op wants to assert there does not exist a set that contains every other set beside itself. As I first wrote it, the statement merely assets there does not exists a set containing every other set. It could be possible that there exists the set of all sets but there does not exists a set that contains every set beside itself. (Certainly this is not possible in the presence of any set theory like $ZFC$.)

Comment: @William `the statement merely assets there does not exists a set containing every other set` and I think that's exactly what's being asked. That's up to interpretation though.

Comment: @GitGud The last line of the OP states that the OP wrote "so I interprete that as, it does not include itself". The way I first wrote it would imply the that the set containing all sets does not exist too. But the OP may want the set of all sets to exist but there does not exists a set containing all sets except itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

"There does not exists a set such that all other sets are its elements."

can be written in first order language of set theory $\mathcal{L} = \{\in\}$ as

$\neg(\exists x)((\forall y)(y \neq x \Rightarrow y \in x) \wedge (x \notin x))$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

You merely wrote that $x$ is not one of its own elements (if $y$ is a member of $x$, then $y\neq x$). The other direction is the other implication (if $y\neq x$, then $y$ is a member of $x$).

Comment: So what you're saying is that I have to swap the term y∈x with the term x≠y? If that's the case - I just learnt that the order matters.

Comment: Clay, the order does matter with implication. Just a quick look in the truth table of $\rightarrow$ will reveal this fundamental truth. Note that $2\leq 3$ and $3\leq 2$ are very different. Think of $\rightarrow$ as $\subseteq$ (and in some places that is actually the notation).